# Microsoft Graph sending email error "Access is denied"

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting error "Access is denied" on sending a test email. Can anyone advise what settings did I missed?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzWWZ.png)

Comment: You can copy the access token and parse it on https://jwt.ms and see if you have the `Mail.Send` permission in it.

Comment: it had this "roles": [
    "User.Read.All",
    "Mail.Send"
  ],

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. :)-

Comment: Did it work for you J Soh?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Client credential flow (App Context), so you should not use `Me` here because the Microsoft Graph doesn't know the meaning of Me as it is not the user context where you are not using your user credentials.

So you should use the code something like this.

```
await graphClient.Users["Userid/UPN"]
    .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Replace your code with above code. Make sure you give the UPN/userid of the user from whom you want to send the mail.

Comment: Depending on your organisation, you may be able to just use `Users[message.From.EmailAddress.Address]` to reference the sending user